# Is this relation transitive? $R=\{(1,2),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$ over $A=\{1,2,3\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

Is this relation $R$ over $A$ transitive?$$A=\{1,2,3\}$$ $$R=\{(1,2),(1,1),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$

Since from the definition a relation is transitive if $\forall x,y,z\in A (xRy,yRz\to xRz)$, so since $3$ isn't in the relation then it isn't transitive?

Comment: Actually the "etc" is important and your reasoning is false.

Comment: If $\neg(xRy \land yRz)$ then the statement is vacuously true on $x,y,z$, so that reasoning doesn't work

Comment: @user2345215 ok I added it, I still don't see how it's transitive. Just like it isn't reflexive since $3,3$ isn't in the relation.

Comment: To prove non-transitivity you need to exhibit a specific trio $x,y,z$ such that $xRy$ and $yRz$ but not $xRz$.  Can you do that?

Comment: @kuhaku Now observe that the implication is always true if the assumption is false.

Comment: Can you find a triple $(x,y,z)\in A^3$ for wich it is *not* true that $xRy\wedge yRz\Rightarrow xRz$? No, so the relation is transitive.

Comment: So the same goes for symmetry? it doesn't have to include all $x\in A$?

Comment: This is why, for definition of equivalence relation, we also include *reflexive*.  And then sneakily ask students whether *reflexive* can be proved from *transitive* and *symmetric*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This relation is transitive. 3 doesn't play any role here since you don't require a transitive relation to be full. Observe that the transitivity here means:  $$(1,2)\wedge(2,1)\in R\Rightarrow(1,1)\in R \\(2,1)\wedge(1,2)\in R\Rightarrow(2,2)\in R$$ and these are found in the relation so it's transitive. In fact that's equivalence relation on $\{1,2\}$ (since it's also reflexive and symmetric there).

**EDIT:** We can justify my remark by definitions ($T$ is the set on which the relation $R$ is defined):

- Reflexivity means $\forall x\in T,(x,x)\in R$ - In our case $(1,1),(2,2)\in R$
- Symmetry means $xRy\Leftrightarrow yRx$. *It doesn't mean that the relation is full*. In our case $(1,2)\in R\wedge (2,1)\in R$. Trivially $(1,1),(2,2)\in R$.

So for these reasons it's an eqivalence relation on $T=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: So symmetry doesn't have to be full either? Is the relation in my question also symmetric?

Comment: @kuhaku YES!!!!

Comment: @kuhaku See my edit please.

Comment: Yes it's easy to see that it's an equivalence relation on $\{1,2\}$ since it's full, but it's just symmetric and transitive on $\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Checking transitive is more than just those two.  For example $(1,2)\wedge(2,2)\in R\Rightarrow(1,2)\in R$

Comment: @kuhaku yes, GEdgar, you are right but I guess it's a bit direct.